# Prove that there exists homomorphism from algebraic structure ($\mathbb{N}, <$) to ($\mathbb{N}, >$) and provide some examples

Tags: abstract-algebra

This homomorphism will be strictly decreasing function, but I think that it can't be defined over natural numbers. Help me to prove that.

Comment: What is your definition of "homomorphism" here?  That $x<y$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think it's probably "$x<y\implies f(x)>f(y)$" - relation on the left implies relation on the right.

Comment: @Eric, That $x < y$ implies $f(x) > f(y)$

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Er, yes, that's what I meant, though the notation I chose to use to express it was admittedly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a function such that $x<y\implies f(x)>f(y)$. Then for any $x\neq 0$ we have that $f(0) > f(x)$, so, the image of $f$ is bounded, and thus finite. But, this is impossible since $f$ must be injective.